# Redirecting back to previous page with inputs

Tags: laravel

Im in preview page and I want to go back to editing page with inputs. I cant use redirect()->back()->withInputs(); because there's no request in preview page. I want to know how to redirect back to edit with my inputs.

These are my links:
http://localhost/project/public/employer/preview 
http://localhost/project/public/employer/edit

Comment: These are local links that only you can access please share the code instead

Comment: I'm just showing my routes

Comment: try `return back()` alone

Comment: So, in my PREVIEW page I will create a route to go back to EDIT page? And in the controller I will put return back()?

Comment: There's no request in preview so it wont show anything

Comment: Ok so simply pass the id of the model to be edited to the preview and then link it backwards to the edit

Comment: Using redirect to controller or route

Comment: it is not yet saved in the database. because it's just a preview before saving to database.

Comment: should i save it in database? even in preview?

Comment: If you want you can juggle the data back and forth. I would recommend that you display the preview in some modal or popup so that you avoid these issues

Comment: Okay, that's a nice idea. Thank you so much